# function not found although package is loaded - R

Tags: r, r-mice

I have been working with an imputed data set using the MICE package (versions 2.2-3.3) in R (versions 3.3-3.5). I am now trying to add some variables to the imputed data set, which historically have worked fine using `cbind.mids()` (in this specific case, it is a Surv object variable from the Surv function). This does not, for some reason, work anymore. Although the `mice` package is loaded, the function `cbind.mids()` is not found.

Minimal example:

```
> library(mice)
Loading required package: lattice

Attaching package: ‘mice’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

cbind, rbind

> cbind.mids()
Error in cbind.mids() : could not find function "cbind.mids"
```

Note 1: `?cbind.mids` still works and finds the help file. Using only `cbind()` from the mice package does not work either, It will merge my new variables to the mids object, but they do not work in subsequent analysis.

Note 2: I have tried reinstalling R, mice and Rstudio. I do not get any other error messages for guidance.

Does anyone know why it behaves like this? Is the `cbind.mids()` function for some reason removed or is it a problem with my system?

Comment: Is it hidden?  Try `mice:::cbind.mids`

Comment: Well, it's there: `getAnywhere(cbind.mids)`returns "A single object matching ‘cbind.mids’ was found\n
It was found in the following places\n
  namespace:mice", but it doesn't show up in the results from methods(cbind). I'm wondering if it wasn't registered properly. Sometimes authors make function names that have periods in them but they really are not part of an S3 group. Try `mice:::cbind.mids`

Comment: According to the package source and the documentation, this is working as intended. `cbind.mids` is not supposed to be used directly.

Answer (score 1):

the `cbind.mids()` is ''in'' the `cbind()` function from the `mice` package. In R console, write `?cbind`, then choose the one from the `mice` package, then at the bottom (see also) click on `cbind.mids` and look at the examples. You'll see that the function `cbind` is doing `cbind.mids` automatically when needed. At least I am pretty sure this the case, just like the merge function in `data.table` is name `merge.data.table` but you are only writing `merge` when using the function. Tell me if it works for you.

Edit : Try using the format from the example. If it doesn't work then maybe the function is not updated/used anymore in the package?

Edit 2 : Official note on `mice::cbind()` :

> "The standard base::cbind() and base::rbind() always dispatch to
>   base::cbind.data.frame() or base::rbind.data.frame() if one of the
>   arguments is a data.frame. The versions defined in the mice package
>   intercept the user command and test whether the first argument has
>   class "mids". **If so, function calls cbind.mids(), respectively
>   rbind.mids(). In all other cases, the call is forwarded to standard
>   functions in the base package."**

Comment: Why doesn't `cbind.mids*` appear in the result of `methods(cbind)`? (You have only demonstrated that `cbind.mids` has a help page.

Comment: Right, I suspected that, and maybe the error is a result of me misinterpreting the actual problem. What is strange is that using cbind.mids(mids, SurvObj) used to work fine, but not anymore. Merging a mids object with a vector seems to work  with cbind(mids, vector). When I try to merge with a vector of SurvObjects the merge works, but doing anything with the resulting mids object fails, and I get the error message "Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Argument 40 must be length 74958, not 149916".

Comment: @42- It doesn’t appear in the list because it’s not called via S3 dispatch, it’s calling it manually. S3 dispatch for `cbind` is broken. :-(

Comment: @Wernicke The same thing is happening with the "rbind.mids" function too. They probably updated the package so you don't need to write the long form anymore (altough I find it kinda annoying). Also, I would need a sample of your data (or a reproducible example) to help you a bit more with this error message. Edit : Go read the second edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use function "cbind" as described in the R documentation of function "cbind.mids {mice}". It works also with Surv object variables.

```
require(mice);
require(survival);

with(lung, Surv(time, status))
cbind(
  x = Surv(heart$start, heart$stop, heart$event)
  ,y = Surv(heart$start, heart$stop, heart$event));
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I can answer the original question and the one I asked Konrad. The `mice` function masks the base S3 `cbind` function. There was notice of this as I loaded mice, but I didn't pay sufficient attention to it. So any call to `cbind` after mice has been loaded first goes through this function (rather than the usual S3 UseMethod-dispatch). I think it's more helpful to think that the usual S3-dispatch is "masked" or hidden from view, rather than saying it is "broken":

```
> `cbind`
function (...) 
{
    if (is.null(attr(list(...)[[1]], "class"))) 
        return(base::cbind(...))
    if ("mids" %in% attr(list(...)[[1]], "class")) 
        return(cbind.mids(...))
    else return(base::cbind(...))
}
<bytecode: 0x1b399908>
<environment: namespace:mice>
```

So the original S3 functions are there, just lying under the surface in whatever namespace they were defined in:

```
> getS3method('cbind', 'mids')
Error in getS3method("cbind", "mids") : S3 method 'cbind.mids' not found
> getS3method('cbind', 'data.frame')
function (..., deparse.level = 1) 
{
    if (!identical(class(..1), "data.frame")) 
        for (x in list(...)) {
            if (inherits(x, "data.table")) 
                return(data.table::data.table(...))
        }
    data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)
}
<bytecode: 0x51233f0>
<environment: namespace:base>

> getS3method('cbind', 'sf')
function (..., deparse.level = 1, sf_column_name = NULL) 
{
    st_sf(data.frame(...), sf_column_name = sf_column_name)
}
<bytecode: 0xb380a80>
<environment: namespace:sf>
```

(I'm not sure this answers any change in behavior from previous versions of the mice package. For that one would first go to `news(pac='mice')`

```
V2.41    10jul2017 SvB
ADDED    New feature: `where`argument to mice
ADDED    New `wy` argument to imputation functions
ADDED    New mice.impute.2l.sys(), author Shahab Jolani
UPDATE   Many simplifications and code enhancements
FIXED    Broken cbind() function
```

It doesn't say in what manner the `mice::cbind` function broke or into how many pieces.

```
V2.33    11apr2017 SvB
CHANGED  Stylistic changes to mice function (thanks Ben Ogorek)
CHANGED  calls to cbind.mids() replaced by calls to cbind()
```